# Происхождение слова шаг и крок.

Tags: этимология

Отвечая на вопрос о происхождении слова год, я задумался над этимологией существительных  крок и шаг. И если про крок говорится то, что произошло это слово от праславянского *korkъ «нога», то о шаге мало что известно. Моя версия - звукоподражание (шаркать). А что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Answer (score 1):

Практически во всех словарях указывается, что шаг происходит от о.-с. segъ.

В др.-рус. языке и других славянских языках слова "шаг" с этим значением нет (сравнить: болг. стъпка), поэтому оно считается трудным в этимологическом отношении. В словарях впервые отмечено  в 1704 году.

Родственными словами могут быть: сигать, досягать/посягать, сажень. У Даля есть "сяжок", на который можно "сягнуть".

Comment: О сягать я слышал, но это не очень убедительно, т.к. значение его "скакать", "достигать", а так же "касаться"(отсюда "присяга"). Хотя, возможно, вы и правы. Неплохо было бы почитать какой-нибудь старинный текст, где "сяг" употреблялся бы в значении "шаг".

Comment: Пословица у Даля: Сторожкая девка на сяжок не подпустит.

Comment: Спасибо, уже кое-что.